# Transparent text with text-shadow in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, transparent, css

When using `color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);` in conjunction with `text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);`, Internet Explorer seems to inherit the transparency of the text-shadow from the text itself, causing the shadow not to appear at all.

JSFiddle example (view in IE):
http://jsfiddle.net/495dZ/1/

Is there a clever pseudo-class technique to work around this? Or maybe something using jQuery to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: Seems like there isn't currently a way of doing this as far as I can tell. I assume there is reason you can't set do color: #000; or whatever background color you are using?

Comment: That comment gave me the idea to move the shadow far enough away from the text that it appears as though the text isn't there. This works fine on a solid color background, but when used with an image, the text would be visible: http://jsfiddle.net/495dZ/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just hide the text off the edge of the window/screen, consider adding a fallback for older versions of IE as well.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/495dZ/23/)**

```
.black-box {
    background: url(http://i44.tinypic.com/2rzwis3.jpg) no-repeat;
    padding: 20px;
}
span.shadow {
    font: 20px Arial;
    position: absolute;
    left:-100px;
    top:-100px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-shadow: 120px 120px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <style>
    span.shadow {
        position: static;
        display:inline-block;
        font: 20px Arial;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2.25);
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<div class="black-box"> 
    <span class="shadow">This is some text.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the most reliable method, with the added benefit of a fallback (wasn't originally a requirement, but a nice addition regardless.) +50 bounty

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Instead of using `position: absolute`, which may not be always possible, I suggest doing something like: `text-shadow: 2000px 0 3px #fff; margin-left: -4000px;`.

Answer (score 2):

A extra `text-shadow` definition for IE 10+ do the trick:

```
.transparent-text-with-shadow {

    color:         transparent;                            // or rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:   rgba(0,0,0,1) 0px 0px 10px;             // for Chrome etc.
    text-shadow:   rgba(0,0,0,1) 0px 0px 10px 0.01em;      // for IE 10+
}
```

The second `text-shadow` definition overwrites the first in IE 10+ only, because IE 10+ supports a fourth length value for the shadow's "spread" - see http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow

In other browsers, like Chrome, the second `text-shadow` definition  overwrite fails, because they do not support a fourth length value for the shadow, and so they will use the first `text-shadow` definition.

(Make sure the fourth "spread" value is very small - so you can't see any rendering differences.)

Answer (score 1):

You can trick IE by moving the real text out of the viewable area and adjust the text-shadow to compensate for the real text offset.

Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/495dZ/36/

**The basic principal:**

```
.shadow { 
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF; // the color will control the text-shadow color
    text-indent:-999px; // offsetting the "real" text
    text-shadow:999px 1px 3px; // fixing the offset of the text shadow
}
```

This will work in certain situations and will require a unique setup for each of those situations. (most likely to set the parent's overflow to `hidden` so the offset text won't be seen. also sometimes you would need to offset it to different directions, depending on the context)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are asking, but IE9 and below doesn't support `text-shadow` property. In IE10 and IE11 your fiddle looked the same as in latest Chrome.

I would suggest using conditionals to target IE9 / IE8 / IE7 and serve plain text.