# CSS Blurry text in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am using the following to give text a blurry effect:

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="blur">Blurry text here</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blur {
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #333333;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=#333333),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=0, direction=0),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2);
    color: transparent;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54xxnxph/) for a preview.

It works perfectly in FF, Chrome and more or less in IE8, however when testing in IE11, the text is invisible.

I know that this is due to `color: transparent;`, however if I change this to something like `color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);`, then the blur is hardly visible.

I never thought I would have to find a fix for IE11 as opposed to IE8, but does anyone know of a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482663/transparent-text-with-text-shadow-in-ie) is a hack to achieve what you want:

"Hide" the text itself out of the screen to display only the shadow :)

Seems to be the only solution for now...

Answer (score -1):

IE10 and higher reads the text-shadow as text-shadow: Xpx Xpx #colour;

In other words, you put the syntax incorrectly. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) for more info on correct usage for text-shadow.

You put:
`.blur {
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #333333;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=#333333),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=0, direction=0),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2);
    color: transparent;
}`

Putting...
`.blur {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color=#333333),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=0, direction=0),
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2);
    color: transparent;
}`

...seems to fix your issue.

You're welcome :)

Comment: The only difference between your code and mine, is that you have defined a horizontal and vertical position. This makes no difference. As mentioned in my question, the transparent colour I have applied is what's causing the problem

Comment: With the code defining a horizontal and vertical position, the text becomes visible in JSFiddle in IE11, which is an improvement none the less.