# How to make transparent text in all major browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a trouble with making transparent text in browsers. Here is a snippet

```
.title {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      font-size: 87px;
      font-weight: 800;
      line-height: 1;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background:    -moz-linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%,#fff 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%,#fff 100%);
      background:         linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%,#fff 100%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;

      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

And result is:

[image: Success image]

But in IE 11 its not working how i can solve this ? Any advice ?

[image: Failure]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482663/transparent-text-with-text-shadow-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

For IE10+ you can try with `-ms-linear-gradient`:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);/* Old Browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5)));/* Chrome, Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%); /* IE 10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%);/* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );/* IE6-9 */
```

If you like, can create this code in this tool:

https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Comment: Not working. I want to fill that text got some transparent with white colored. Above is just changing background color.

Comment: if you can't do with this tool.. i doubt that can be do it by css.

Comment: I don't think there's a solution...Hardly **ANYONE** uses IE nowadays...Just forget about that browser, the main focus is Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera, Microsoft Edge and IE aren't really important they are obselete AF.